# Generic constraint exclusion

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry for asking silly question

Is it possible to enforce constraint on generic in such a way that the given T can be derived 
from any reference Type except some A,B,C (where A,B,C are reference types).
(i.e)

```
Where T : class except A,B,C
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what you want to use this for.

Comment: @Joel After making bit correction I will post my code and explain why do i need it.Thanks Joel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But you could check for these classes at run-time:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    static Foo()
    {
        // one of the following depending on what you're trying to do
        if (typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format(
                "Generic type Foo<T> cannot be instantiated with {0} because it derives from or implements {1}.",
                typeof(T),
                typeof(A)
                ));
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format(
                "Generic type Foo<T> cannot be instantiated with type {0}.",
                typeof(A)
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move the check to a static constructor, it only runs once instead of every time a new instance of the class is created. However, due to debugging issues it's very important to include a proper error message with the `NotSupportedException` in that case. I edited the post to use that method.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only specify that it *does* inherit from a particular type, is a value or reference type, or that it must have a default constructor. Remember that this is for the benefit of the compiler, not the developer. :)

The best you could probably do is throw an exception at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry No.  You can find out how you can constrain [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no negation of types.  The where clause only allows you to contrain to a specific type.