# Is there a generic type-constraint for "where NOT derived from"?

Tags: c#, generics

We can specify a *"derived from"* constraint on generic type parameters like this:

```
class Bar<T> where T : IFooGenerator
```

Is there a way to specify *NOT* derived from?

---

My use-case:  I have a bunch of `FooGenerator`s that are parallelizable, with the same parallelization code for each, but we don't want them to *always* be parallelized.

```
public class FooGenerator : IFooGenerator
{
    public Foo GenerateFoo() { ... }
}
```

Thus, I create a generic container class for generating Foo in parallel:

```
public class ParallelFooGenerator<T> : IFooGenerator where T : IFooGenerator
{
    public Foo GenerateFoo()
    {
        //Call T.GenerateFoo() a bunch in parallel
    }
}
```

Since I want `FooGenerator` and `ParallelFooGenerator<FooGenerator>` to be interchangeable, I make `ParallelFooGenerator : IFooGenerator`.  However, I clearly don't want `ParallelFooGenerator<ParallelFooGenerator>` to be legal.

So, as an auxiliary question, is there perhaps a better way to design this if "not derived from" constraints are impossible?

Comment: `ParallelFooGenerator<ParallelFooGenerator>` already isn't possible, because `ParallelFooGenerator` is a generic type and you didn't specify a generic argument.  For example, `ParallelFooGenerator<ParallelFooGenerator<SomeFooGenerator>>` is possible -- and would allowing such a type really be that bad?

Comment: No it's not possible - allowed constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: @cdhowie: Wow, derp, you're right.  Well, that solves my problem :) But the question could still be useful to others!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731286/generic-constraint-exclusion?rq=1

Comment: I'll move my comment to an answer then.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
public interface IFooGenerator
{
    Foo GenerateFoo();
}

interface ISerialFooGenerator : IFooGenerator { }

interface IParallelFooGenerator : IFooGenerator { }

public class FooGenerator : ISerialFooGenerator
{
    public Foo GenerateFoo()
    {
        //TODO
        return null;
    }
}

public class ParallelFooGenerator<T> : IParallelFooGenerator
    where T : ISerialFooGenerator, new()
{
    public Foo GenerateFoo()
    {
        //TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better design imho. *Adding* an interface one level up rather than restricting inheritage one level down is way cleaner and easier to understand. Each interface and class makes sense on its own.

Comment: @cdhowie solved *my* problem, but I'm marking this correct as it answers the question in the title.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`ParallelFooGenerator<ParallelFooGenerator>` already isn't possible, because `ParallelFooGenerator` is a generic type and you didn't specify a generic argument.

For example, `ParallelFooGenerator<ParallelFooGenerator<SomeFooGenerator>>` is possible -- and would allowing such a type really be that bad?

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is no.

The long answer (still no):

Microsoft puts it well in their [explanation of type constrains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx): "The compiler must have some guarantee that the operator or method it needs to call will be supported by any type argument that might be specified by client code."

The fundamental purpose of constraints is not to prohibit certain types from being used, but rather to allow the compiler to know what operators or methods are supported.  You can, however, [check if a type implements/inherits a specific interface/base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class) at run-time and throw an exception.  With that, though, you will not be able to get a design-time error from intellisense.

I hope this helps.