# Is it possible to restrict the type of variable passed to a .NET method to not be a derived class?

Tags: c#, .net

Can i constrain the type that is passed to my method in a way that catches this type of error when compiling instead of running?

My current code looks like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    SaveAnimal(dog);
}

void SaveAnimal(Animal animal) {
    var isAnimal = animal.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(Animal);
    Debug.Assert(isAnimal, "You can not save dogs!");
}

class Animal {
    public int Legs { get; set; }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    public int TailLength { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so basiaclly you want to allow all `Animal`s but keep the `Dog`s out ?

Comment: Doesn't that break LISP?

Comment: You can't do that as explained by @usr. You could perhaps call another method to filter out dogs before calling the SaveAnimal method?

Comment: If you have another animal, e.g. `Cat: Animal, ISaveable`, then `void SaveSaveable(ISaveable saveable)` can save it. Don't make dogs `ISaveable`, cats are so much better!

Comment: What if I implement `Cat` class as an *exact copy* of `Dog` class (I just copy and paste all the field/methods/properties of `Dog` class while renaming `Dog` int `Cat` when necessary)? Shall `SaveAnimal` *start working*?

Comment: What you really need to ask yourself is: if a dog cannot do something *all* animals can, is a dog an animal at all? (Hint: it's not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way in the language to statically catch this as a usage error.

You can assert this at runtime as you are doing it already. It's against the spirit of inheritance, though, because a fundamental assumption is that derived types must substitute for the base type (the Liskov substitution principle).

Maybe you can make the animal save itself by giving `Animal` a new method `abstract void Save()`. Then, each animal decides what to do. `Dog` can then throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only with a workaround using generics and interfaces.

What you would need to do is to declare 3 interfaces

```
public interface ISaveAbleBase { }
public interface ISaveAble : ISaveAbleBase{ }
public interface INotSaveAble : ISaveAbleBase { }
```

Now you need to give your Animal class a generic parameter and constraint it to be of type `ISaveAbleBase`.

```
class Animal<T> where T: ISaveAbleBase
{
    public int Legs { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can now specify in the derived classes wether they can or cannot be saved:

```
class Dog : Animal<INotSaveAble> 
{
    public int TailLength { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could make your method generic and constrain the type only to aminals that can be saved

```
void SaveAnimal<T>(T animal) where T: Animal<ISaveAble>
```

Now the result looks the following way:

```
void Main()
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    SaveAnimal(dog); // does not compile

    Animal<ISaveAble> generalAnimal = new Animal<ISaveAble>();
    SaveAnimal(generalAnimal); // compiles      
}
```

Disclaimer: this construct would also allow you to have a general `Animal` that cannot be saved:

```
Animal<INotSaveAble> generalAnimalNotSave = new Animal<INotSaveAble>();
SaveAnimal(generalAnimalNotSave); // does not compile
```

PS. This answer is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11195066/5174469)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way how to do this, but there is a simple *(and stupid)* workaround.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var dog = new Dog();
      SaveAnimal(dog);
    }

    private static void SaveAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
      var isAnimal = animal.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(Animal);
      Debug.Assert(isAnimal, "You can not save dogs!");
    }

    private static void SaveAnimal(ICanNotSave animal)
    {
      Debug.Fail("Can not save");
    }
  }

  internal class Animal
  {
    public int Legs
    {
      get; set;
    }
  }

  internal interface ICanNotSave
  {
  }

  internal sealed class Dog : Animal, ICanNotSave
  {
    public int TailLength
    {
      get; set;
    }
  }
}
```

When you have two `SaveAnimal` method, where one of for `Animal` and other is for a interface, that is implemented on all descendants that can not be saved, the compiler report a CS0121 error.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.SaveAnimal(Animal)' and 'Program.SaveAnimal(ICanNotSave)'

Remember it is still possible to use the `SaveAnimal` method when you use it like this: `SaveAnimal((Animal)dog)`

Comment: If there is a base class, then often (not always, but often) there is a collection of that type `List<Animal>` to do something what all `Animal` can do. Then your hack won't catch the dog.

Comment: You are right. I forgot this one problem, but this can never be solved for compile time *(unless you make similar dirty work for the collection class)*.